# sourcing bash profile for root users

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Apologies in advance if this question is going to annoy the hell out of everyone as I appreciate, it's been asked in various ways many times before.  Please be assured, I have read the archives and have tried at least some of the suggestions but still cannot resolve the (simple) issue. Hopefully someone can provide an answer and I can feel appropriately humbled.  FYI, for the avoidance of any ambiguity, I'm going to use absolute rather than relative paths.

When I log in, I do so as user `adam`.  The aliases in `/Users/adam/.bash_profile` are loaded and I can use them immediately upon pulling up a terminal.  I don't use a `.bashrc` file and that's fine.

Every now and then, I switch to root by typing `su` into the terminal and then entering my password.  The prompt changes and I am now root user.  My question is this: immediately upon becoming root, can my root bash profile be loaded without me having to manually source the profile file?  The reason I know it doesn't happen automatically is because I have the same aliases in my root profile file and my `/Users/adam/.bash_profile`.  After becoming root user, unless I type in `source [root_profile_file]`, they don't work.  I have tried setting up the following permutations and then switching to root via the terminal but none of them automatically source the profile/aliases (note, I don't have any of the options below set up concurrently so I don't think I'm confusing the system):

**Option 1:** put my aliases in `/etc/profile`

**Option 2:**

- in `/etc/profile`, insert `[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc`
- put my aliases in `/etc/bashrc`

**Option 3:**

- in `/etc/bash_profile`, insert `[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc`
- put my aliases in `/etc/bashrc`

**Option 4:**  put my aliases in `/var/root/.profile`

**Option 5:**

- in `/var/root/.profile`, insert `[ -r /var/root/.bashrc ] && . /var/root/.bashrc`
- put my aliases in `/var/root/.bashrc`

**Option 6:**

- in `/var/root/.bash_profile`, insert `[ -r /var/root/.bashrc ] && . /var/root/.bashrc`
- put my aliases in `/var/root/.bashrc`

Please note, with any of the above, if I switch to root and then type `source root_profile_file` the aliases are loaded but only if I do indeed source the file manually.  Perhaps I've totally misunderstood how bash works and it's not possible to source a profile file automatically after switching to root but I'm hoping there is a simple solution.  Thanks in advance to anyone who's taken the time to read this message.

Answer (score 15):

The problem you are encountering is that when you run `su` by itself, you are not entering a 'login' shell. This means that your environment, working directory, and everything except uid/gid remain the same of the original user.

Login triggers do not execute, and you experience the issues you describe.

A simple solution to a simple problem:

`su -`

From the `su(1)` man page:

> The **su** command is used to become another user during a login session. Invoked without a username, su defaults to becoming the superuser. The optional argument **-** may be used to provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.

Also:

> ```
>    -, -l, --login
>        Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
> ```

If you `su` into a login shell, bash will behave as you expect, and automatically source the appropriate files on "login", without the need for overly hacky workarounds.

Comment: I will however second Hai Vu's notes: You really, really, really should never `su` nor work as `root`.

There is `sudo` for that purpose, or you can work in such a way that you don't require root privileges at all.

Comment: Thank you to both you and @Hai Vu.  "su -" does the trick and yes, completely understood, root should generally be avoided.

Comment: I already knew to add the '-' after the su command, but still was not getting my .bash_profile for the root user sourced.  Florian Bidabe's and patrix's answer below about changing the root shell from sh to bash fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 9):

Actually root uses `/bin/sh` (old bourne shell), `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` are read by bash.

It becomes tricky as those files may use functionality not available in `sh`. Even if you `source .bashrc` or `source .bash_profile`, you will still have some issue with complex functions for instance.

One way to solve this is to run

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/root UserShell /bin/sh /bin/bash
```

to switch `root`'s shell to `bash`.

Comment: Root's `/bin/sh` uses `/var/root/.profile` file. Credit to @Matic's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105744/248873)

Answer (score 6):

When I absolutely must, I `sudo bash` which makes me root but with JRobert's environment.  My .bashrc contains:

```
# Prompt: 'jrobert@JRiMac ~' in green (red, if I'm root), '$' in white
if [[ $UID == 0 ]]; then
   export PS1="\[\e[1;31;40m\]\u@\h \W\[\e[0m\]\$ "
else
   export PS1="\[\e[32;40m\]\u@\h \W\[\e[0m\]\$ "
fi
```

, to make the root-prompt glare back at me in RED to emphasize that I'm now (more) vulnerable to my own [pick one:  brashness, dumbness, fat-finger tendencies, unwillingness to take good advice, up s.creek - don't drop the paddle].

Answer (score 3):

I am using `sudo -i` to switch to to root user. In this case, shell configuration is read from `/var/root/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I advice against `su` as it is dangerous, just search for it and you know why. On to your question, the root account works the same way your account does: it source ~/.bash_profile and/or ~/.bashrc. I don't know which one, but my intuition leans toward *~/.bashrc*, so you might want to try to put your aliases there. Here is a suggestion:

```
su           # type password to get into root account
vi ~/.bashrc # put your aliases there
exit         # exit your root session
su           # try again to see if your aliases works
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this is to run the following to switch root's shell to bash:

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/root UserShell /bin/sh /bin/bash
```

This solution has fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score -2):

if you have only one 'default' user and the root user you can put `alias su="su -"` on .bash_profile of the 'default' user and you get the effect you want. Works and with no hacky things.