# Synchronise or share .zshrc between accounts

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave, zsh

I have a standard user account (in Mojave using zsh shell) and based on [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Zsh/Guide#Prompts) I have added this to my .zshrc to show a prompt like `[user@computer] ~ $`

```
if [[ $UID == 0 ]]; then
   PS1="[%n@%M] %~ # "
else
   PS1="[%n@%M] %~ $ "
fi
```

I changed root shell to zsh with `sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh` but `sudo su` gives an incorrect (presumably default) prompt unless I re-source my `.zshrc`:

```
[hali@A1398] ~ $ sudo su
A1398# echo $PS1
%m%#
A1398# source .zshrc
[root@A1398] /Users/hali #
```

Based on [sourcing bash profile for root users](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45999/115093) and [What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361957/115093) I copied my `.zshrc` for root to use with `cp ~/.zshrc /var/root/`

Similarly I also have a hidden admin account set up according to this [Apple doc](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203998) and so `su admin` also shows its' default prompt unless I also do `cp ~/.zshrc /var/admin/`

If I copy both it then works as I want - the user(`%n`) is shown before the computer name(`%M`):

```
[hali@A1398] ~ $ sudo cp .zshrc /var/root/
[hali@A1398] ~ $ sudo cp .zshrc /var/admin/
[hali@A1398] ~ $ sudo su
[root@A1398] /Users/hali # su admin
[admin@A1398] /Users/hali $ exit
[root@A1398] /Users/hali # exit
[hali@A1398] ~ $
```

Is there any way to use one copy of `.zshrc` for these three accounts to share or somehow automatically keep them in sync as I make further changes to this file?

Comment: Does `sudo su -l` fix the issue,in other words, prevent the need to source `.zshrc` ?

Comment: @fd0 - unfortunately `sudo su -l` didn't work so I make symlinks for `.zshrc` and also ran `touch /var/root/.histfile` as `zsh-newuser-install` didn't seem to work for root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a symlink. It uses the `ln` command in the terminal

`ln -s ~/.zshrc /var/root/.zshrc`

You can replace /var/root with whatever you need to. This will create a file named .zsrhc in /var/root that is linked to the original copy in your home directory. Please note that you may need `sudo` before this if you do not have file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Zsh will read up to 5 "global" rc files on startup depending on its shell classification, ie. login or non-login, interactive or non-interactive and their content is available to all zsh users. These files are /etc/zshenv, /etc/zprofile, /etc/zshrc, /etc/zlogin, and /etc/zlogout. They are read in conjunction with 5 "dot files", usually found in your home directory .zshenv, .zprofile, .zshrc, .zshlogin, and .zshlogout. In your case, /etc/zshrc would be a good candidate.

You can replace-

```
if [[ $UID == 0 ]]; then
   PS1="[%n@%M] %~ # "
else
   PS1="[%n@%M] %~ $ "
fi
```

with this one line

```
PROMPT='[%n@%M] %~ %(!.#.$) '
```

The `%(!.#.$)` is a conditional statement which reads:

if the shell is privileged (!) then place the text `#` at the end of the prompt else place a `$` at the end of the prompt. (This syntax seems alot like `csh`syntax.)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you - this answer works very well too.  I assumed before trying it that `/etc` would be protected in Catalina but it seems not.  I just need to decide whether to make changes global or not.